# react-intl provider in parent package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, internationalization, react-intl

I have a react project "App" that requires another package "AppComponents" which in turn requires "UI" package.

> App (has Intlprovider) => AppComponents (useIntl works) => UI (useIntl does not work)

I added the Intl Provider in "App", and when I use the hook "useIntl" in "AppComponents" package, it works fine. But when I use that hook in the "UI" package, it doesn't work, saying there's no provider:

> Uncaught Error: [React Intl] Could not find required `intl` object.  needs to exist in the component ancestry.

I'm using:

react-intl v6.0.4

react v18.0.0

node v18.0.0

npm v8.6.0

"App":

```
import { useMemo, useState, createContext } from 'react';
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { MessageFormatElement } from 'react-intl';

export type TTranslationData = Record<string, string> | Record<string, MessageFormatElement[]>;

export interface II18nContext {
    locale: string;
    setLocale: (newLocale: string) => void;
    setTranslation: (data: TTranslationData) => void;
}

export interface II18nProviderProps {
    children: ReactNode;
}

const I18nContext = createContext<II18nContext | null>(null);

function I18nProvider({ children }: II18nProviderProps) {
    const [locale, setLocale] = useState(navigator.language);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState<TTranslationData | Record<string, never>>({});

    const value = useMemo(
        () => ({
            locale,
            setLocale,
            setTranslation: (data: TTranslationData) => setMessage(data),
        }),
        [locale],
    );

    return (
        <I18nContext.Provider value={value}>
            <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={message}>
                <App />
            </IntlProvider>
        </I18nContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

"UI" package (not working):

```js
import { useIntl } from 'react-intl';

...
function Searchbar(props: SearchbarProps) {
    const intl = useIntl();

    ...
    return (
        ...
        {intl.formatMessage({
            id: 'searchbar.placeholder',
            description: 'React UI search bar placeholder',
            defaultMessage: 'Search',
        })}
        ...
    );
    ...
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why but it works now after I deleted the vite cache and used npm links. Very odd but what's new when using windows to develop :p